# Show/Hide Div based on the text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to know if there's a way to show/hide div if a paragraph tag has text or not.

If there's text in the p tag the div needs to show, if not it needs to be hidden.

```html
<p id="my-text-is-used-to-hide-you">I'm full</p>

<div class="something">Try to hide me</div>
```

Comment: What will you be using to access the value of the <p> tag ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a combination of [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty), then targeting the [sibling `<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator).  Something like this:

```css
p:not(:empty) + div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p id="my-text-is-used-to-hide-you">I'm full</p>

<div class="something">Try to hide me</div>
```

Naturally, these selectors could drastically change if the HTML you're using is more complex than what you're showing.  But the concept itself is at least *possible*.

If the real target structure is more complex than CSS can reasonably handle then you'd be looking at JavaScript for more robust functionality:

```js
if (document.querySelector('#my-text-is-used-to-hide-you').innerText !== '') {
  document.querySelector('div.something').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<p id="my-text-is-used-to-hide-you">I'm full</p>

<div class="something">Try to hide me</div>
```

Comment: I really like you simplicity answer to not script and to use pure CSS when possible. With your scripting part however I would recommend to rather go for `classList` + `toggle/add/remove` instead of `style` for specificity weight reasons.

Comment: Hey this script version worked for me, made it an if else loop to display if there's text and hide both if there's nothing, thanks for this @david

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, here's an example. You can use the :empty sudo-class.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const watch = document.querySelector("#watch");
  watch.textContent.length ?
    watch.textContent = "" :
    watch.textContent = "I'm full"
});
```

```css
#watch:empty + .target {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p id="watch">I'm full</p>
<div class="target">Try to hide me</div>
<button>Toggle Text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution (recommended):

```
var p = document.getElementById("my-text-is-used-to-hide-you");
var div = document.querySelector("div");

div.style.display = "none";

if(p.innerText != "") {
    div.style.display = "block";
} else {
    div.style.display = "none";
}
```

or this "short" one (not recommended unless you like "compact" style code):

```
document.querySelector("div").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("my-text-is-used-to-hide-you").innerText != "" ? document.querySelector("div").style.display = "block" : document.querySelector("div").style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score -1):

Vanilla JS solution

```
const p = document.queryselector("#my-text-is-used-to-hide-you");
const div = document.queryselector(".something");
const haveText = p.innerText.length;
if(!haveText) div.style.display = "none";
else div.style.display = "block";
```

Comment: Please read [answer]. Your answer effectivly is 
a [link only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) and as such does not fit the guidelines 
as an answer.